# Meaning of 'not a sufficient condition'

Tags: logic

$A$ is a sufficient condition for $B$ means $A \rightarrow B$. But what does it mean by '$A$ is not a sufficient condition for $B$'? Does it mean $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$? I don't think so as they don't sound the same to me.

But if this is the case, then what should be the correct expression for 'not a sufficient condition for'?

Comment: I disagree that they don't sound the same. It's a direct translation. "Not X" directly translates to $\neg X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all confusion about implication is due to the fact that $a\implies b$ does not mean "for all." It is always talking about concrete $a$ and $b$, without variables.

So you might say "For all integers $n$, it sufficient to know that $n$ is divisible by $4$, to know that $n$ is divisibie by $2$.

I think *usually* when we say $A$ is sufficient for $B$, we are really saying

> For all $X$, $A(X)$ implies $B(X)$.

With that interpretation, "not sufficient" means "There exists X, such that $A(X)$ is true and $B(X)$ is not true."

In propositional calculus, there are neither quantifiers ("for all" or "there exists") nor variables. If you are talking "sufficiency" in propositional context, then the other answers are correct, "not sufficient" would mean "A and not B."

Comment: I did worry about this. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually adding "not" before a property $P$ means $\neg P$. Here it does mean $\neg(A\to B)$. This is logically equivalent to $\neg(\neg(A\wedge\neg B))$, that is, $A\wedge\neg B$. This is in accordance with our intuition that $A$ not being a sufficient condition for $B$ means that it is possible to have $A$ but NOT $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $A\wedge\neg B$ is not false, or, put another way, that there is a situation in which $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

When we say "$A$ is sufficient for $B$" we mean that the truth of $A$ *guarantees* the truth of $B$.   That $B$ is true if $A$ is too.

When we say "$A$ is not sufficient for $B$" we merely mean the truth of $A$ *permits* the falsity of $B$.   $B$ *may be* false when $A$ is true.

The denial of a guarantee is not a guarantee of anything.

---

Having a married brother is *not sufficient* to be an aunt, because you can:

- Have a married brother and not be an aunt.
- Not have a married brother and be an aunt.
- Not have a married brother and not be an aunt.
- Have a married brother and be an aunt.

---

Having a ticket in the lottery is *not sufficient* to winning the lottery, because you can:

- Have a ticket and not win.
- Have a ticket and win.
- Not have a ticket and not win.

Although you cannot win if you do not have a ticket.  Having a ticket is necessary to win.

Comment: Could you clarify something, @Graham Kemp ? In your example about an aunt, cases case 4 is straightforward. Case 1 makes sense because perhaps that married brother do not have any children. Now, I do not understand cases 2 and 3. You started saying "Having a married brother...", so the possibility of not having a married brother is ruled out ? Perhaps, I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The sister of a mother is an aunt, as is the sister of a single father.  The main point: it is neither sufficient *nor necessary.*

Comment: Perfectly clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of sufficient condition is a modal notion, involving some kind of necessity. So, trying to reduce it to truth-functions is bound to fail. As a first and quite rough approximation 'Property P is sufficient for property Q' can be analysed as $\Box \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$, where $\Box$ has a S5-semantics and quantifier domains are restricted to world domains.

So, the sentence 'the property of being a bearded agent is sufficient for the property of being an agent' is true iff in every possible world everything that both exists and is a bearded agent in that world is an agent in that world. This seems to yield the correct result.

Conversely, there are worlds where nothing is bearded but some things are agents. These worlds show that being an agent is not sufficient for being a bearded agent.